# Google Maps does not display any tiles, works fine in developer device

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed an Android application with Google Maps. Maps work fine when I checked with my device, or even emulator. But when I delivered it to client he says only "no tiles displaying, just grid lines and Google logo at bottom left". What could be wrong?

Comment: My first guess is that your (virtual) test device is different from the client's, or that it's running a different version of Android.  I'm not going to bother with a second guess, because without further information we're all shooting in the dark.

Comment: So i had to ask him which android device, version your using...ok but u saying tht displaying maps depends on firmware version and device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you haven't got the right API KEY for the Google maps widget.

When you sign the application, you have to use the same keystore and obtain an API key. You get the MD5 fingerprint of the keystore you are using to sign the application go here, http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html  put the finger print and get the API key, then in your maps widget,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:apiKey="0G0LHKCCJvhmNvdpZijAqg76V63Cs6DTBbq2-Pw"
        android:enabled="true" android:clickable="true" />
```

put the `api_key`

Comment: am able to display map in my device..,, but not showing my clients device

Comment: I understand. But when you are coding in eclipse you probably have the api_key for your debugging keystore not the keystore you are signing your apk with.

Comment: means i have to create own keystore and should that api key rather than from default folder keystore

Comment: How do you normally create an apk? Don't you sign it?  http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html  . An easier to do it on eclipse is right click the project, go to android tools -> export signed application -> either create a new keystore or use an existing one.

Comment: thanx its working now...i used the existing keystore file when signing my application rather than new one.