# Android Get MAP key

Tags: android, android-layout

How to get google maps APIs key.I am running eclipse on Ubuntu and the path /home/tom/eclipse and android is in /home/tom/android or is it that the i need to register somewhere to get the key.Please let me know..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989088/google-maps-on-android-question/5989187#5989187

Answer (score 0):

To get the map keys, follow the below steps:

Go To your .android folder in the home directory of the user that have installed the sdk.
Then locate the debug.keystore file.
In command line use the below command to get the SHA1 fingerprint from debug.keystore file.

> keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Then copy the SHA1 fingerprint.Go to Googles developer console and create a new project, and there click on credentials. Then create new key. Create new android Key.
Here put your SHA1 fingerprint;your package name.

Then you will get the map key.

And  dont forget to switch on the Google map Android V2 to ON in the Google dev console.

I hope this helps.