# How to get Map api key?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps does not display any tiles, works fine in developer device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989088/google-maps-does-not-display-any-tiles-works-fine-in-developer-device)

I have gone through whole procedure of getting map api key .But when I enter my Md5 fingerprint it shows invalid .
Could somebody help me.
Is there any other way to get it work?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information. What procedure did you go through? Where are you entering it? What do you mean by 'shows invalid'? Be specific

Comment: Everything is written here: [Obtaining a Maps API Key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Comment: I have got the md5 fingerprint but when i use it here code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html .It shows Invalid fingerprint!!!

Answer (score 3):

**i think this is right a way to get key ::**

To get certificate fingerprint (MD5) follow the simple steps below:

You need to get the keystore file for getting the certificate fingerprint (MD5).
Your keystore file can be found at the following path
**"C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Android"**

(Or)

**"C:\Documents and Settings\.android"**

Keystore file name is "debug.keystore" file.
Copy the "debug.keystore" file to some other folder (ex: - "D:\Androidkeystore\") (its user friendly to use).
Open command Prompt and go to the Java installed directory. ("C:\Program Files\Java\\bin")
Then type the below line (given in box) and press enter.

**keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\AndroidKeystore\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android**

Here the MD5 certificate fingerprint is **"64:88:A2:FC:AA:9F:B1:B0:CA:E4:D0:24:A8:1E:77:FB"**

this is working actually........but im getting small error here

this is my path-`C:\ANDROID\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore"C:\ANDROID\debugkey\debug.keystore"-storepass android -keypass android`

keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, android is not a legal c
ommand

and finally i have solve from here ::

[**For more ..**](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-google-map-application-example)

as you got fingerprints copy it and past in Sign Up page. you got a **key successfully**

Comment: I have got the md5 fingerprint but when i use it here http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html .It shows Invalid fingerprint!!!

Comment: make sure your key-store file is valid

Comment: Sorry ,but what does that mean? Valid file?

Comment: you can try on this also http://sunilsuthar02.blogspot.in/2012/12/get-map-api-key-in-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

if your are using windows do this

```
C:\>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

in linux

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /home/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin ---> Here key tool is available ------

C:\Users\HB.android\debug.keystore ---> keystore path

// This may be different My UserName is HB so replace with your's

**Note:without keytool u cannot get the api key and cannot execute the command**

The command goes here  ---->

**C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin> keytool -list -keystore C:\Users\HB.android\debug.keystore**

**FF:82:84:27:33:43:C1:58:DC:4D:AC:F0:3C:A0:BF:7A**

The above is ur MD5 CERTFICATE

http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html for Registration

Click the above link  login and get your api key. Have fun... Happy Mapping

**P.S: Dont forgot to extend MapActivity in which you are using the map layout**

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Click the above link for help