# Map does not show on other mobiles but appears on my mobile device

Tags: android

I have developed an android application which uses Google maps api v2. map works just fine on my mobile but it does not even appear on other mobiles. I have installed .apk file on other mobiles but a white screen appears. Map is not shown. Can any body tell me why is it happening?

Comment: That probably has something to do with the map key. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989088/google-maps-does-not-display-any-tiles-works-fine-in-developer-device